# Get the value from jsp in post method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've next code:

```
 <ol class="word-list">
    <c:forEach items="${words}" var="thisItem">
 ****

<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user">
    <fieldset>
```

And I've controller for post method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@Validated User user,
                    BindingResult bindingResult, 
                    Model model){
```

How to get ${words} variable into my controller?

Comment: To have them posted, they must be inputs of the form. You could use hidden fields. But since they seem to come from the server anyway, you could simply get them the same way you got them to print them in the JSP.

Comment: It isn't the best way to get them from the server because it is the random list. My way is: if I set the existent user I seneded to next page, if the user is incorrect I stay on this page, but the word list is null. So that list should looks like nothing happend. And for this goal I want to reinput that list. How I can do this?

Comment: Store it somewhere (in the session for example), or regenerate it the same way as the first time. If using a pseudo-random number generator, using the same seed will generate the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. Can you add an answer for my question? I use store value in session mechanizm.

Comment: Answer your own question with the solution you came up to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by storing words variable into the session.

Answer (score 0):

using like this way

```
model.addAttribute("word", "word");
```